# Word to describe sending of personalized message to all?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have 3 different kinds of sending a message in my system.

1. Send specifically - I will send a message directly (Like one on one chat)
2. Send All - Something like a general message (All can receive my message)
3. Send to all but specifically - I will send a message to all of my users but all of them will receive their own, individually personalized message.

An illustration is like this:

**Send specifically**

Server: (Send) Hi -> Client A: (Received) Hi

**Send All**

Server (Send) Hi -> Client A: (Received) Hi
   -> Client B: (Received) Hi
   -> Client C: (Received) Hi

**Send to all but specifically**

Server (Send) Hi Client A -> Client A: (Received) Hi Client A
Server (Send) Hi Client B -> Client B: (Received) Hi Client B
Server (Send) Hi Client C -> Client C: (Received) Hi Client C

Comment: To send to all you *broadcast*.  (In the computer-related trades this is much more idiomatic than "mass-send" or some such.)

Comment: @HotLicks Does "broadcasting" carry the connotation of *personalized* individual messages?

Comment: @A.P. -  "Personalized individual messages" is known as "junk mail".

Comment: @HotLicks (A) Not necessarily. You (and many others) can voluntarily subscribe to a useful notification and a bulk mailer will send each person a personalized message when the event occurs. (B) You answered my question about broadcasting by dodging it.

Comment: OP didn't say that "send all" meant individualized messages.  He said "Something like a general message".

Comment: @HotLicks I think that's exactly what he did. OP is asking about a good name for a feature that sends a message with a *personalized* greeting: "Hi, Client A", "Hi, Client B", etc. I obviously agree that "broadcasting" would work for what OP chose to call "Send All", but that's not the question, if I'm reading it right. But I'll grant it's somewhat unfortunately worded.

Comment: @A.P. - Read it again, for the first time.

Comment: @HotLicks My point is, the question is not about "Send All", but about personalized messages. Read the title. For some reason, you chose to contrast "broadcast" (which doesn't work for personalized messages) with "mass-send" or "bulk-send" (which does) in your comment. "Broadcast" is not even relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need something short (for button labels, for example), consider:

1. Send
2. Send All
3. **Mass-send** or **bulk-send**

This would be analogous to the terminology used in email marketing tools. When you need to do an email blast (send a large number of subscribers a personalized individual message), you use [*mass mailing software*](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-mostly-free-mass-mailing-applications/), or [*bulk email software*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_email_software).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

> Send each a personalised message.
>   --> **Send personalised**

or

> Send an individually personalised message to all.
>   --> **Send individually**

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***mail-merge***.

> *n.* (computing) a software product that uses a file (database) of names and addresses, together with a template document, to produce
>   multiple copies of a letter, each personally addressed to a different
>   recipient.
>
> *v.* to carry out such a process [Wiktionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/mail-merge#2mHIfWuw75AufECF.99)

Comment: That would work nicely for email, but not for chat messages. Imagine a chat program with a button that says "Mail merge". You would expect it to send email, yet all it does is send an instant message.

Comment: Yes, thank you for considering that I will use this in my system.This seems to be good but it doesn't fit if I will put it in a system.